# R Speed up vectorize for square matrix

Tags: r, performance, matrix, regression, symmetric

Anyone able to help me speed up some code:

```
n = seq_len(ncol(mat)) # seq 1 to ncol(mat)
sym.pr<-outer(n,n,Vectorize(function(a,b) {
    return(adf.test(LinReg(mat[,c(a,b)]),k=0,alternative="stationary")$p.value)
}))
```

Where `mat` is an `NxM` matrix of `N` observation and `M` objects, e.g:

```
    Obj1 Obj2 Obj3
1      .    .    .
2      .    .    .    
3      .    .    .
```

`LinReg` is defined as:

```
# Performs linear regression via OLS
LinReg=function(vals) {  
  # regression analysis
  # force intercept c at y=0
  regline<-lm(vals[,1]~as.matrix(vals[,2:ncol(vals)])+0)

  # return spread (residuals)
  return(as.matrix(regline$residuals))
}
```

Basically I am performing a regression analysis (OLS) on every combination of Objects (i.e. `Obj1, Obj2` and `Obj2,Obj3` and `Obj1, Obj3`) in `mat`, then using the `adf.test` function from the `tseries` package and storing the `p-value`. The end result `sym.pr` is a symmetric matrix of all `p-values` (but actually it's not 100% symmetric, see [here for more info](http://quanttrader.info/public/betterHedgeRatios.pdf)), nevertheless it will suffice.

With the above code, on a `600x300` matrix (600 observations and 300 objects), it takes about 15 minutes..

I thought of maybe only calculating the upper triangle of the symmetric matrix, but not sure how to go about doing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with some dummy data

```
mdf <- data.frame( x1 = rnorm(5), x2 = rnorm(5), x3 = rnorm(5) )
```

I would firstly determine the combinations of interest. So if I understood you right the result of your calculation should be the same for `mdf[c(i,j)]` and `mdf[c(j,i)]`. in this case you could use the `combn` function, to determine the relevant pairs.

```
pairs <- as.data.frame( t( combn( colnames( mdf  ),2 ) ) )
pairs
  V1 V2
1 x1 x2
2 x1 x3
3 x2 x3
```

Now you can just apply your function row-wise over the pairs (using a t.test here for simplicity):

```
pairs[["p.value"]] <- apply( pairs, 1, function( i ){
  t.test( mdf[i] )[["p.value"]]
})
pairs
  V1 V2   p.value
1 x1 x2 0.5943814
2 x1 x3 0.7833293
3 x2 x3 0.6760846
```

If you still need your p.values back in (upper triangular) matrix form you can cast them:

```
library(reshape2)
acast( pairs, V1 ~ V2 )
          x2        x3
x1 0.5943814 0.7833293
x2        NA 0.6760846
```

Comment: Thanks @Beasterfield, that did the trick. For anyone interested in the results: `600 observations of 15 variables: Original: 1.91s, Optimized (Beasterfield): 0.86s`; `600 observations of 300 variables: Original: 733s, Optimized: 359s`. So a speedup of `2x~`, very impressive! Thanks again.

Comment: Just realised.. `2x` speedup because it does half the amount of calculations haha!

Comment: @Ubobo I thought this was the entire idea, to cut the runtime into half by calculating only the upper triangular matrix :-D